# jQuery *= Selector not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

For some reason, I am not able to get this to work under IE8.  Works fine in Chrome.

This is the element I am looking for:

```
<input type="text" captures_name="default" name="firstname" required="S01 S02"/>
```

this the jQuery (1.9.1) I am using:

```
$("input[captures_name='default'][name='firstname']") //Match

$("input[captures_name='default'][required*='S01']") //Does Not Match

$("input[captures_name='default'][required*='S02']") //Does Not Match

$("input[captures_name='default'][required='S01 S02']") //Does Not Match
```

I want to be able to find the element based on a single value in the `required` attribute.  I'm sure I am just over looking something.... Can someone lend me a pair of eyes?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is'nt the `required` attribute in HTML5 a boolean attribute ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the W3C specs for HTML5 the required attribute is a boolean attribute, meaning it's either true or false.

> required = "required" or "" (empty string) or empty.
>
> Specifies that the element is a required part of form submission.

So you can set it like:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" required />
<input type="text" name="firstname" required="required" />
```

It can't really hold any other values, even if jQuery might be able to get such values using `attr()`. The correct way to check it or set it would be `.prop('required')` and `.prop('required', true)` etc.

In other words your selector is based on invalid markup, which is not a good idea.

Comment: I changed required to required_for and it now works!  Thanks for  your help.  I initially reported that this did not work, but it was a caching issue.